# Deep linking is not working on IOS to navigate to a selected screen

Tags: sharepoint, deep-linking, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have defined this deep linking:

1. Inside the `App OnStart` I set this to capture the parameters:

   ```
    Set(varNavigationModule,Param("module"));
    Set(varNavigationUserEmail,Param("user"));
    Set(varNavigationStatus,Param("status"));
    Set(varNavigationType,Param("type"));
   ```
2. Inside the App StartScreen, I set this to redirect to `DashBoard` screen:

   ```
    If(Lower(Param("module"))="workorder",('DashBoard'),Home)
   ```
3. Then I am sending a link inside the email as follow:

   ```
    https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/*********?module=workorder&status=new&user=****@*****.com
   ```

This is working well on my desktop browser, but when i click on the link inside my outlook mobile app the power app mobile will open but will show the home screen and not the dashboard.. I am using iPhone 11 & iOS version 16.5.1

Any advice, why deep linking is not working on my mobile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use **deep links** with the iOS Power Apps application, you need to follow this [article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/mobile/mobile-deep-links#supported-urls-parameters-for-a-canvas-app).

URL should not start with `https` but with `ms-apps`:

```
ms-apps:///providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apps/<appID>?tenantId=<tenantId>&restartApp=true
```

So, in your case, web URL with custom parameters could be rewrite as:

```
ms-apps:///providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apps/<appID>?tenantId=<tenantId>&restartApp=true&module=workorder&status=new&user=****@*****.com
```

Of course, you have to manage two URLs depending the user device.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply.. so in this case i will need to manage 3 versions of the URL i am sending in the email? one for web browsers + one for IOS + one for Android devices? but when i am sending the email i do not know what will the user use to open the app... so any suggestion how to manage this? Thanks

Comment: The last paragraph of the article (`Troubleshooting`) talk about this. `ms-apps://`will work with both iOS and Android. But as Power Apps is an enterprise feature, devices are probably manages by the IT: you can force or restrict the installation of the Power Apps mobile application. Furthermore, you can create a webpage (on Azure, Power Pages, etc.) to detect the user device and redirect with the right URL (http or ms-app depending). But it's very common to send communications to employees with different links (for example when a unique message is sent in different language)